# Solving for an expression between an equation and its derivative

Tags: partial-derivative, projectile-motion

We are given that a projectile starts off with initial vertical velocity $V_0$, and reaches maximum height $h$ at constant time $T$.

The height $y$ of the projectile at time $t$ is given by:

$y=V_0t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$

Then clearly from the first statement:

$h=V_0T-\frac{1}{2}gT^2$

Given that, I'm looking for a function $f(h,t)$ which equals the height of the projectile at time $t$ whose maximum height is $h$. My first thoughts were that:

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=V_0-gt$,

Because the projectile stops at the top:

$V_0-gT=0$

Solving for g:

$V_0=gT$

$g=\frac{V_0}{T}$

I think I can plug g back into $y$ because nothing in it is a function of lowercase $t$?:

$y=V_0t-(\frac{V_0}{T})t^2$

I don't know if that works, or not. If it does, I can solve for $T$ in $h=V_0T-\frac{1}{2}gT^2$ and plug it in, and then I'm done.

**EDIT**

That final solve would ensure $g$ is still in the equation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to capitolize the V_0 the first time.

Comment: although theres an answer already i'm a bit confused. are you looking for an expression which relates the projectiles relative position to it's highest point at any time t?

Comment: No. h is the absolute maximum of the projectile, and t is time.

Comment: My main question is whether the substitution of g is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The altitude is given by
$$y (t)=-\frac {1}{2}gt^2+V_0t $$

and the velocity by
$$V (t)=\frac {dy}{dt}=-gt+V_0$$

the maximum height $h $ is reached when $V (T)=0$

thus
$$T=\frac {V_0}{g} $$
and
$$h=y (T)=\frac {1}{2}\frac {V_0^2}{g}$$

Comment: I forgot the 1/2 too. Oops... Thanks.